# HTML string in python file doesn't execute as expected

Tags: python, html, python-3.x

When I type the code below, it gives me a blank HTML page. Even though I put a `<h1>` and a `<a href>` tag. Only the `<title>` tag is executed. Does anyone know why and how to fix it?

Code:

```
my_variable = '''
            <html>
                <head>
                    <title>My HTML File</title>
                </head>
                <body>
                    <h1>Hello world!</h1>
                    <a href="https://www.hipstercode.com" target = "_blank">Click me</a>
                </body>
            </html>'''

my_html_file = open(r"\Users\hp\Desktop\Code\Python testing\CH\my_html_file.html", "w")

my_html_file.write(my_variable)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It might be because you aren't closing the file properly. Try `with open(...) as my_html_file: my_html_file.write(my_variable)`.

Comment: It works for me. Mind you, I use a different name for the html file. I see the title, the h1 heading and the link.

Comment: How are you opening the html file?

Comment: I've tried to open it with Chrome and Microsoft Edge @BillBell. What is your file named?

Comment: Just temp.html.

Comment: Oh I just noticed that I only get the issue when I run it in IDLE (when I click on ``Run module``). But it works fine when I save and close the text editor and then click on the program (so it gets executed in cmd). I wonder why that is.

Comment: Try adding my_html_file.close() to the end of the script. It's likely that IDLE hasn't flushed its buffer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @bill Bell said, it's probably because you haven't closed your file (so it hasn't flushed its buffer).

So, in your case:

```
my_html_file = open(r"\Users\hp\Desktop\Code\Python testing\CH\my_html_file.html", "w")
my_html_file.write(my_variable)
my_html_file.close()
```

But, **this is not the right way to do it**. Indeed, if an errors occurs in the second line for example, the file'll never get closed. So, you can use the `with` statement to make sure that it *always* is. (just as @Rawing said)

```
with open('my-file.txt', 'w') as my_file:
    my_file.write('hello world!')
```

So, in fact, it's like if you did:

```
my_file = open('my-file.txt', 'w')
try:
    my_file.write('hello world!')
finally:
    # this part is always executed, whatever happens in the try block
    # (a return, an exception)
    my_file.close()
```